# MST of an subgraf.

Tags: graph-theory

I find myself yet again stucked in one of the assignment's problems for my Graph Theory Course at my local university.

Let G = (V, E) be a connected (multi)graph and c : E → R be a cost function on its edges.
Let $T^∗$ be a minimum cost spanning (MST) tree of G (with respect to c). We said that a connected subgraph H of G is c-extendable if $T^*_H$ = (V (H), E(H) ∩ E($T^∗$)) is a spanning tree of H.

Here is where i am getting stucked.

~Prove that if H is c-extendable, then $T^∗_H$ is a MST of H.

The solution which I've worked my way through a certain point is supposing that $T^*_H$ is not the MST of H.Considering this I assumed that there is a MST of H called $A^*$.A property of $T^*_H$ considering $A*$ is $\sum_{(e \ from \ c(T^*_H))} c(e)$ > $\sum_{(f \ from \ c(A^*))} c(f)$ . How should i proceed next?

Any hint is welcomed!

Comment: Could your class please start collaborating so that you're only asking questions once?  This is like the fourth time this question has come up in the past week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to recognize that $A^*$ can be used to construct a spanning tree $\bar A$ of G with lower total cost than $T^*$ which gives a contradiction because $T^*$ was presumed to have the smallest possible total cost.

$\bar A$ can be constructed by taking all the edges of $A^*$ and all the edges of $T^*$ that aren’t in $T*_H$.

All you need to do from there is prove that $\bar A$ is in fact a spanning tree, and that it has lower cost than $T^*$.

Comment: Proving that its cost is lower than $T^*$ is in fact easy.But the real problem surface when it comes to proving that $ \bar A$ is indeed a spanning tree.As i am putting it is obvious that is has n-1 arcs but i still have to somehow prove its conexity.How should i proceed ?

Comment: The edges in T* outside of $T^*_H$ get you from anything outside H to some vertex in H, the edges of A* allow you to move around in H. It is important that if you take a path in T* to a vertex in H, the last edge in that path not in $T^*_H$ Connects to the first vertex of that path in H. Can you flush that out into a proof?